# PhalconPHP DI : Initializers

Tags: php, dependency-injection, phalcon

I am currently testing phalcon php for a project, and I am looking for a way to automatically inject certain classes automatically based on an implemented interface.

[The Dependency Injection reference](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html) has an example where if a class implements `Phalcon\DI\InjectionAwareInterface`, it will automatically inject the DI into that class.

What I want to do is similar. If a class has for instance `Aranea\Db\DbAdapterAware`, it should automatically inject the DbAdapter in that class. I am looking for something similar to what Zend Framework 2 does (https://juriansluiman.nl/article/121/interface-injection-with-initializers-in-zend-servicemanager), where during DI config you can specify initializers like this:

```
'initializers' => array(               
    'logger' => function($service, $sm) {
        if ($service instanceof LoggerAwareInterface) {
            $logger = $sm->get('logger');
            $service->setLogger($logger);
        }
    }
),
```

If this is not automatically possible in PhalconPHP, I was thinking of overriding the `FactoryDefault` class and implement it myself. What would be the right place to inject this logic? In the get* methods, or rather in the set* methods? I assume that a method is not initialized during DI initializing but on first call, so get* would sounds more appropriate?

Thanks for your advice,

Jeroen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Dependency Injection reference has an example where if a class implements `Phalcon\DI\InjectionAwareInterface`, it will automatically inject the DI into that class.

That is not entirely true, what it means is that the DI gets (automatically) injected when the service is resolved given it implements this interface, the DI doesn't magically appears there just because the class implements some interface.

> If a class has for instance `Aranea\Db\DbAdapterAware`, it should automatically inject the DbAdapter in that class.

That is sort of how it works (not technically) if your class extends the `Phalcon\DI\Injectable` (or implements the `InjectionAwareInterface` in the same way as `Phalcon\DI\Injectable`). Inside `Injectable` there is a `__get` magic, which returns the service from the DI if the service exists. In other words stuff get injected only in the DI, and other classes lookup for services in there.

To inject your own services you can either pass them in your configuration to the DI or extend the `DI` or `FactoryDefault`. The difference between the two is that `FactoryDefault` already comes preconfigured with the useful services, which you might not need though.

> I assume that a method is not initialized during DI initializing but on first call, so get* would sounds more appropriate?

Yes, there is a `Phalcon\DI\Service` object that represents the service and resolved when called for the first time (if it's a shared service) or resolved every time (if it's not). You normally would want all your services to be shared, otherwise this often becomes a bottleneck, e.g., when resolving a non-shared database adapter, which establishes the connection every time you call it…

**PS:** Note, for it to work as you want it with the `DbAdapter` you can do a few things:

1. Add the adapter getter and return `DI::getDefault()->getShared('db')`;
2. Extend the `Phalcon\DI\Injectable` and set the DI when the class is created, so it can lookup for services.
3. Every time you need the adapter simply get it from the DI like shown in the first option.